# Reading literal float or 5.1f from config file not working with Eigen::Vector4f in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I have a config file which contains this `crop_min_x = -5.0f`. I am trying to read this from my C++ program using the below code

```
std::ifstream config_file_path("config.txt");
      std::string line;
      while (std::getline(config_file_path, line)) {
          std::istringstream sin(line.substr(line.find("=") + 1));
          if (line.find("num") != -1)
              sin >> config.num;
          else if (line.find("crop_min_x") != -1)
              sin >> config.crop_min_x;
      }
```

where config is a structure as below

```
struct Config {
        int    num;
        float crop_min_x;
        };
Config config;
```

I am trying to use it in `Eigen::Vector4f min_pt (config.crop_min_x, -5.0f, -5.0f, 1.0f);` to use it with PCL library to crop the PointCLoud. But the PCL code does not work. It gives error (`[pcl::KdTreeFLANN::setInputCloud] Cannot create a KDTree with an empty input cloud!`) at a later stage, even after cropping, in KDTree part which sounds weird but it is. When I change this line to `Eigen::Vector4f min_pt (-5.0f, -5.0f, -10.0f, 1.0);` , everything works fine but I want to make the program flexible by reading this value from a config file. Please suggest a way.

**[UPDATE]**:  I think I was missing reading `crop_max_x/y/z` parameters because of which the issue was happening. It is working fine now after including them.

Comment: Not sure you are telling all relevant parts of your problem. When `crop_min_x=5.1f`, then passing `Vector4f(crop_min_x, -5.0f, -5.0f, 1.0f)` fails, but `Vector4f(-5.0f, -5.0f, -10.0f, 1.0)` works? This does not look like a parsing problem nor an Eigen problem, but passing wrong parameters.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. I tried to print the `config.crop_min_x` variable as well. If text file stores `-5.0f`, it gets printed as `-5` and if its stored as `-5.1f`, it prints as `-5.1`. I am not able to get the `f` which seems to make a difference somehow. I did some further hit and trial by declaring `float my_x = -5.1f;` and using it like `Eigen::Vector4f min_pt (my_x, -5.0f, -5.0f, 1.0f);` and it failed again. Though, I could see `-5.1` as its value when printed using `std::cout` but no `f`. So far, only when I type the values myself in `Eigen::Vector4f min_pt`, the code works!

Comment: Parsing with `sin >> config.crop_min_x;` will not read an “f” character. `5.1f` is a form of numeral for source code, and the `f` indicates a type in the C++ program. Reading a number with `>>` does not read numbers in the same forms as constants in source code. If you want to do that, you must write your own parsing code. Or you can remove the “f” from the text file. In any case, update the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil : The minimal example which I could think of would require installing ROS2 foxy and building a workspace/ package as there needs to be a pointcloud message for processing. I can share the zip file for the workspace and the command to build if it is OK?

Comment: Based on the description in the question, nothing more is needed for a minimal example than packaging the first sequence of code into a `main` routine, adding some code to output values showing that something undesired was read, and supplying sample contents for “config.txt” (these could actually be built into a string stream, so no separate file would be required). As noted, what you are likely getting is a trailing “f” in the input stream blocking subsequent inputs. You should be diagnosing that issue directly, not its downstream effects.

Comment: @chtz and @Eric Postpischil : Sorry to bother you. I think I was missing reading `crop_max_x/y/z` parameters because of which the issue was happening. It seems to work fine now after including them.